# Is it possible to hover on all the rows upto the the rowspan column

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

Assume I have removed the border from the rows within the spanned rows. Would it be possible to expand the hover to the entire span like below in the image.

Currently it is hovering only on the single row. Here is the code https://webcomponents.dev/edit/p6LI1RTN6vlxrGv3UOwf/src/app.html

[image]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: https://webcomponents.dev/edit/p6LI1RTN6vlxrGv3UOwf/src/app.html

Comment: I would suggest you read the [ask] page before asking, which strongly discourages including links to or images of code. Include the minimum code required to reproduce the problem in the question itself. For more info, read how to create a [mre].